# .NET application fails to run from Network Share and RDP Shell

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, cas, rdp, terminal-services

I'm trying to run my .NET application, that resides in a network share from our domain, using a RDP Client.

When starting a "full" RDP session (that is, opening the whole desktop) and then running my application from the *.exe* file, everything works fine.

But when I set this same *.exe* as the `Startup Application Path` from the RDP Client , I get the following error:

*(PS: I clipped the stack trace to the calls I found myself more important)*

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Environment' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Incorrect Parameter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   (...)
   at System.AppDomain.get_Evidence()
   (...)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.LoadGlobalPropertiesFromAppConfig() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Environment.cs:line 212
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Environment..cctor() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Environment.cs:line 198
```

As I work with shadow-copied files, I set a new AppDomain when the application has just begun (the .exe entry point):

```
<STAThread()>
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim currentDirectory As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory)
        Dim runtimeDirectory As DirectoryInfo = New FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location).Directory

        Dim appDomainStartupSetup As New AppDomainSetup
        appDomainStartupSetup.ApplicationBase = currentDirectory.FullName
        appDomainStartupSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true"

        Dim appDomainStartup As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("StartupAppDomain", Nothing, appDomainStartupSetup)
        Dim entrypointLoader As LoadBaseFiles = appDomainStartup.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.CodeBase, "MyClass.LoadBaseFiles")
        entrypointLoader.RuntimeDir = runtimeDirectory.FullName ' Setup the 'entry-point' object 
        entrypointLoader.StartupEntryPoint() ' Starts the Application

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error Handling Here
    End Try
End Sub

Public Class LoadBaseFiles
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    ' Startup stuff here...

End Class
```

**More Info**

- [Content of my ApplicationEntryPoint.exe.config file;](http://pastebin.com/8XZnd902)
- I had set the CAS Policy to Full Machine Trust, but I'm not sure this still applies to .NET 4.0;
- The Remote Desktop (Terminal Services) Server runs Windows Server 2003;

**EDIT:**

- If I copy all the assemblies to a local drive (**C:**) and run my application from there, it will work fine.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an argument or pointing to an unavailable resource.

a) Is the Working Directory set for the application?

b) Is the Working Directory available to the user on login?

Comment: There's no nhibernate section in my app.config - all my NHibernate stuff is done programmatically. The App.Config content I posted in the link above is 'as it really is'. The question is why the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)` call (and sub-call's) end throwing this `Exception`.

Comment: Sorry, I actually completely failed at reading RDP there. Updated my answer.